# JQuery Datepicker along with dateformat

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Am kinda new at Jquery DatePicker. What i want to do is allow user to select a fromDate based on that the toDate datepicker min&max date is set. But i need to use dd/mm/yy format. but when i use this the functionality in onchange vanishes. Can any1 help me with this ?
below works perfect but am unable to implement the datepicker in dd/mm/yy format

```
 $("#Date_FromDate").datepicker({                
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: firstDate,
            maxDate: lastDate,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#Date_ToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                var choosenDate = new Date(selectedDate);
                var choosenDateQuarter = Math.floor((choosenDate.getMonth() / 3));
                var choosenDateQuarterStartDate = new Date(choosenDate.getFullYear(), choosenDateQuarter * 3, 1);
                var choosenDateQuarterEndDate = new Date(choosenDateQuarterStartDate.getFullYear(), choosenDateQuarterStartDate.getMonth() + 3, 0);
                lastDate = choosenDateQuarterEndDate;
                $("#Date_ToDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", choosenDateQuarterEndDate);
            }
            
        });
        $("#Date_ToDate").datepicker({               
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: firstDate,
            maxDate: lastDate,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#Date_FromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
```

Comment: put dateFormat in both the datepicker options.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$("#Date_ToDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

Or

```
$("#Date_ToDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

Comment: earlier i had used inside datepicker itself ie., 

         $("#Date_FromDate").datepicker({    
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",              
            defaultDate: "+1w",
...etc
but this took away the entire functionality of onchange

Comment: yes!
there are two textboxes implementing datepickers
1. FromDate when i select a value
the value in Todate datepicker sets the max and mindate based on the calculation

Comment: learn from this example: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-range.html

Answer (score 0):

Pass `dateFormat` as a parameter.

Use your required format instead of null. More information about dateformats is [here.](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html)

So your code changes from

```
 $("#Date_ToDate").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: firstDate,
            maxDate: lastDate,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#Date_FromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
```

to

```
 $("#Date_ToDate").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: firstDate,
            maxDate: lastDate,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#Date_FromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
```

You will have to parse your `firstDate` and `lastDate` before assigning it to the minimum and maximum as below:

```
  var minDate= $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', firstDate);
  var maxDate= $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', lastDate);
```

Comment: are u meaning to pass the dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy' like that?

Comment: well anyways its not working :(
wud it be anything to do with the version effect??

Comment: @ArchieDave NO nothing to do with version

Comment: @ArchieDave I had missed comma in my answer, have you added tat after dateFormat

Comment: yes i tried that....option
when i add dateformat as u have mentioned above whatever code i had mentioned in the onClose becomes invalid
should i specify it explicity inside onclose event for the New Date() to be in dateformat dd/mm/yy???

Comment: for example                 var choosenDate = new Date(selectedDate);
 should i specify choosendate to be in dd/mm/yy???
if so how do i do that?

Comment: minDate: firstDate,
            maxDate: lastDate, here is the problem

Comment: to  implement $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy',firstdate)
should i add the juery.ui-datepicker.js file for it to work???

Comment: @ArchieDave Where are you getting firstDate and Lastdate? those are also wrong

Comment: i calculate them 



var firstDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), quarter * 3 - 3, 1);
                     var lastDate = new Date(currentQuarterStartDate.getFullYear(), currentQuarterStartDate.getMonth() + 3, 0);

Comment: Keep them in the same format as the format you have given for datepicker in dateFormat

Comment: yes i did that but when i did and added jquery.ui.datepicker.js
am getting an exception " missing number at position+iValue"
should i add any more .js files???

Answer (score 0):

Both [user1386320](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874279/jquery-datepicker-along-with-dateformat/14874321#14874321) and [Bhushan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874279/jquery-datepicker-along-with-dateformat/14874322#14874322) are right.

Not to confuse you much more write given code above your code then format the values which you are getting in variables firstdate and lastdate if they are already in dd/mm/yy then no need to format.

```
$("#Date_FromDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
$("#Date_ToDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```